# I have no idea why my if statement not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

This is my code:

```
def main(subject):
    subject = input("Which subject do you want to learn?")
    if subject == English:
        print("I glad to hear that!")
```

When I run **python3 "File name.py"** in Linux terminal, nothing happened.

I tried to define the "English" but I got a syntax error in the compiler.

Am I missing something in my code to run the if statement properly?

Comment: Add quotes around English, like that: `"English"`

Comment: *"I tried to define the "English""* Can you show how?

Comment: Nothing happened.

Comment: @Austin def main(subject, english): at the line 1

Comment: What is the `suject` argument for? You don't use it anywhere.

Comment: @SamLo: That is not the line 1, I see from your question.

Comment: @Austin Because in that code, I have an error message, so I didn't add to my question.

Comment: Is your function `main()` being called anywhere? Otherwise it is to be expected that the code inside this function is not run (because it is not being called).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def main():            
    subject = input("Which subject do you want to learn?")
        if subject == "English":
            print("I glad to hear that!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

change your script and re-run. 
You missed calling the function.

Comment: Hiding the call to the function in `if __name__ == "__main__":` is important, because we don't actually want to run the code if someone imports this module.

Comment: yes, true that. Thanks for update.

Comment: Thanks! It works. But what is the () uses for in the def main? When do I need to define something in it? And why in the last line has a main(), what does it do to the code?

Comment: Well,  you can also pass subject inside it and call the function with the parameter. Considering your use case here, you simply want to get a subject from user and check if it's English. So, you do not pass anything to function as such but execution depends on user input so empty parameters inside the function.

When you add the __name__ thing, the main() function will not execute when you import this module in some other script.

Please accept the answer if it worked and if you understood the explaination.

Comment: The link isn't working.

Comment: thanks @SamLo :) [link]( https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-does-the-if-__name__-__main__-do/) check this for detailed understanding

Answer (score 3):

You need to call the function.

And you need quotes around `English`.

```
def main():
    subject = input("Which subject do you want to learn?")
    if subject == "English":
        print("I glad to hear that!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I've removed the unused `suject` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect nothing happens because your code defines a method and never calls it.

Have you tried to do this instead?

```py
def main():
    subject = input("Which subject do you want to learn?")
    if subject == "English":
        print("I glad to hear that!")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

What I have changed:

- actually call your `main` method when we run the script
- remove the unused `suject` parameter
- use quotes around `"English"`

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I have some question about this code, what is the parameter uses for in the(), when do I need to add an object in it? And what is if __name__ == "__main__" uses for? In the last line, what is the main() uses for?

Comment: On the line with `def`, you can specify a list of parameters between the parenthesis. If you want your method to accept parameters, that is where you give them name. Once you have `def function(parameters): ...` you have defined a method, but you still have to call it. That's what the `main()` on the last line does. The `if __name__ == "__main__"` is a condition that will only be True when the file is run as a main script, like you do, but will be false if someone imports your code. We only want to run when it's run as a main script.